# Is there a minhag amongst some to wear a kittel on Rosh HaShanah?

Tags: yom-kippur, rosh-hashanah-new-year, yekke, kittel

The universal Ashkenazi minhag is to wear the kittel on Yom Kippur.

I have heard of some who wear the kittel also on Rosh HaShanah. Is this a true minhag? I suspect it might be a Jeckishe (German) minhag, but I'm not so sure.

Comment: "a true minhag" What's that? Do you mean are there people who actually do this?

Comment: @DoubleAA I mean does anyone do this because of minhag, not just misguidance.

Comment: possible dupe https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/10536/759

Comment: "I mean does anyone do this because of minhag, not just misguidance" - I DO! Have been doing it since I was a late teen-ager. My family is not Yekkish, though, my maternal grandparents lived in Belgium for many years so gained some Germanic minhagim. However, the majority of people in my shul, also not Yekkish, wore a kittel on Rosh Hashanna. I highly doubt they were misguided, and I know I was not misguided by them. I think there is something in O.C. mentioning wearing a kittel on Rosh Hashannah. I'll see if I can locate it.

Comment: Sorry, but I will be marking this as a dupe, in a minute...

Comment: Noticed on your profile "Midland, TX". I hope you weren't affected by huge difficulty due to Hur. Harvey.

Comment: @DanF - Boruch Hashem, I am 477 miles away from Houston. Houston's in East Texas, and Midland's in the far West Texas. There's barely any rainfall here at all, so no I have not been affected...personally. Emotionally, I was recently in Houston about two weeks ago picking up a car and I davened in the Chabad that got totally wrecked in the Hurricane! Five people from the community there have died (Boruch doyon ho'emes) and it makes me sad to think one of them might have been the guy swaying next to me in shul. :( Thanks for your thoughtfulness and remember to daven for their safety in Houston.

Comment: "The universal Ashkenazi minhag is to wear the kittel on Yom Kippur." It isn't - many polish/Glician Jews never wore a kittle - my own family only put on because of 'al tifrosh min hatzibbur'. I believe ger still don't

Comment: @Orangesandlemons - No idea but the kittel is mentioned in the Shulchan Aruch.

Answer (score 2):

Charnobyl dynasty followers wears kitel on Rosh HaShanah, it is their minchag.