# Which officiants wear a kittel on Rosh HaShanah?

Tags: minhag, synagogue, rosh-hashanah-new-year, kittel

In many Ashkenazi congregations, most of the congregants do not wear a *kittel* on Rosh HaShanah; however, a number of the officiants do wear a *kittel*.

It seems to me to be fairly common that at least the *chazzanim* for *shacharit* and *musaf* wear a *kittel*, as well as the *ba’al tekiah*.

What about other officiants? The *makri*, the *ba’al keriah*, the *gabbaim*, the rabbi, the *chazzanim* for *pesukei dezimra, arvit* or *mincha*?

Are there any sources noting who wears a *kittel* on Rosh HaShanah, or is this a hyper-local and/or very recent custom and thus unlikely to be noted in writing?

Comment: Hi @JoelK - in the UK as I'm sure you know in many shul most people have the custom to wear a kittel and not just those officiating?

Comment: Related - https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/10536/why-the-difference-in-minhagim-about-wearing-a-kittel-on-yom-kippur-only-or-als

Comment: @Dov Right. My question is about those congregations where that is not the case

Comment: From the various sifrei halacha I looked at, it just mentions the custom of wearing a kittel and not anything about who exactly wears it?

Comment: Just b'derech agav, the Kaf HaChaim gives a nice overview - https://www.sefaria.org/Kaf_HaChayim_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.581.79.1?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en

Comment: I did , breslov